# How to build Polymer's components/platform/platform.js from scratch?

Tags: build, polymer

How can you build `https://github.com/Polymer/platform/blob/master/platform.js` from the source? (That is, the concatenated and minified/uglified version of `platform.js`.)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't produce exactly the file as `https://github.com/Polymer/platform/blob/master/platform.js`, but the following is very close to the 0.1.4 release:

```
$ git clone git@github.com:Polymer/tools.git
$ cd tools
# Manually edit bin/pull-all-{elements,polymer,projects}.sh
# and change DEFAULT_BRANCH to 0.1.4
$ ./bin/pull-all.sh
$ cd components/platform-dev
$ npm --silent install
$ grunt
$ cp build/platform.js{,.map} ../platform
```

(Answer assembled from the [Getting the code](http://www.polymer-project.org/getting-the-code.html#git) section of the website, [`make-release.sh`](https://github.com/Polymer/tools/blob/master/bin/make-release.sh) from Polymer/tools, and some hacking. A similar approach should work for `polymer.js`.)